# Curl или file_get_contents, что быстрее в моем случае?

Tags: curl, php, синтаксический-анализ

Здравствуйте! **Написал вот такой парсер:** он извлекает содержимое тега <title>, вопрос после кода:

```
function page_title($url) {
    $fp = file_get_contents($url);   // получаем страницу (тут можно по разному даже через CURL)
    if (!$fp) 
        return null;            // Если страницу не получили выйти и отправить указатель на null

    $res = preg_match("/<title>(.*)<\/title>/siU", $fp, $title_matches); // Найти title
    if (!$res) 
        return null; // если ничего не нашли выйти и отправить указатель на null

    $title2 = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $title_matches[1]); // уберем мусор переводы строк
    $title = preg_replace('/(\([0-9]).*/', ' ', $title2); // уберем лишнее из заголовка
    $title = trim($title);
    return $title;   // Отдадим заголовок
}

$cont = mysql_query("SELECT id, title, start_price FROM data WHERE title='' LIMIT 100", $db);
if (!$cont) {
echo "<p>В базе нет записей</p>";
exit(mysql_error());
```

}

```
    if (mysql_num_rows($cont) > 0) {
    $myro = mysql_fetch_array($cont);
    do {$meta = page_title("http://site.ru/show_item.php?item=".$myro['id']);      echo "<br>\n";
      printf("%s - (<a href='http://site.ru/show_item.php?item=%s'>%s</a>)",$meta, $myro['id'], $myro['id']);
    } while ($myro = mysql_fetch_array($cont));
} else {echo "<p>В базе нет записей</p>";
}
```

Здесь используется **file_get_contents** ! Обработка происходит не особо быстро, 100 стр/мин. Увидел в сети мнение что через cURL будет быстрее. Подскажите будет ли быстрее в моем случае через cURL и если несложно, какие изменения в коде сделать, а то никак не соображу как написать?
И еще ... возможно скорость маленькая из-за того, что качает код всей страницы, а нужно только содержимое тега <title> ... думал может кусочек скачивать который будет содержать тег, как считаете?

Comment: > а нужно только содержимое тега <title> ... думал может кусочек скачивать который будет содержать тег, как считаете?

каким образом?

> Обработка происходит не особо быстро, 100 стр/мин. 

Зависит от сервера, но вообще а) терпимо и б) зависит в значительно большей степени от синхронности (однопоточности), а не от транспорта

Comment: @Etki "каким образом?", ... что то вроде fread($handle, 4096))

Comment: @cheh1, вы думаете, скорость от этого сильно изменится, а сервер не будет формировать и посылать ответ целиком?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

используйте мультикурл, можно сделатьт хоть сто потоков одновременной обработки, главное чтобы сервер не забанил за частые запросы (если чужой) и что бы канал позволял.

Comment: @wolfston Спасибо, за совет! Реализацию не подскажешь для моего случая, а то я с cURL мало знаком!

Answer (score 1):

Основная проблема в быстродействии в том, что вы ждёте ответ от сервера, хотя процессор в это время не нагружен. Вам необходимо делать параллельные запросы через [curl_multi_init](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-multi-init.php) . Там и пример есть.